# Which is better for programming STM32F103C8T6? Using Arduino IDE or STM32CubeProgramming?

Tags: arduino, stm32, programming, software, ide

STM32 is can programming using Arduino IDE, but I am confusing about which is better for programming this device, and what is the deficiency about this two software for programming STM32. (I am learning for using STM32F103C8T6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not very clear if you are talking about "programming" the STM32, which means: pushing the binary code into the chip.
Or if you mean "writing the code" which is called "software development".

I assume you are taking about software development.
It depends on your needs.
Using the Arduino IDE, you can use a variety of libraries for driving a lot of sensors, screen, LED, etc. Most of the details are hidden to you and if the project is simple enough, life will be easier.

Using the STM32 MX Cube + IDE is more involved, but also more powerful.
You use the MX Cube software to setup your chip and its peripherals. It will generate a basic project from here.

Then you use the STM32 IDE to modify the generated code and add your logic.
It's a more "professional" way of doing it. Therefore, the IDE is packed will a lot of advanced features which may look scary to a beginner.

In conclusion:

If you are a beginner, I suggest that you work with the Arduino IDE, which is more friendly. Somewhat limited, but as long as you don't have demanding requirements it will be fine.

Comment: The IDE is irrelevant. The libraries are. You either use the ST's libraries or Arduino's libraries. Even the compiler is the same, GCC.

Comment: Some of the Arduino libraries call the ST libraries. Arduino being limiting? That’s garbage. You can call the same ST library functions cubemx does if you so desire.or write your own code.  If you want a ‘better’ IDE, use platformio.